# Oracle entity framework migrations with temporal tables

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to create a migration for an oracle database, with temporal tables, which are included in OnModelCreating method like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<SomeEntity>().ToTable(options => options.IsTemporal());
```

But migrations completely ignores this settings, just creates migration without additional "Period" columns. Am I missing some package or oracle entity framework can't handle temporal tables?

Comment: What versions of everything are you running, and what packages?

Comment: Did Migrations make a connection to the database?  I've seen a number of Migration issues recently that were failing due to the connection not completing.  I suspect the Microsoft code for Migration is not very robust and needs upgrading since more than one group is having similar issues.

Comment: As I know EF Core Oracle provider do not support flashback queries. Isn't?

Comment: I´m using latest packages: Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore & Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools. And yes, connection to database is fine. Migrations works well, just they ignore temporal.